# How do you replace "spend X day" in an indirect form (e.g. with a pronoun)?

Tags: grammar, phrase-request, pronouns

This is a bit hard to explain but here's an example:

> I wanted to spend Christmas with him, but he said he had __ with his family in Ireland this year.

What to fill in the blank (a phrase that doesn't include *spend*)?

Initially, I wrote *to do it* but a native English speaker said it wasn't quite correct.

Comment: Are you looking for a whole phrase?  *to spend it* would work there.  *to do it* does sound a little weird.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, a phrase that doesn't include *spend*. I updated my question.

Comment: This is a noun rather than a verb (phrase), but you could put "plans" in the blank and it scans perfectly well.

Comment: I guess you could say "he had *to be* with his family".  That's the most fluent thing I can think of other than "to spend it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than "spend," you may say "to be," and it means the same thing as with "spend"

Another way to say it, with a different meaning, is "plans," as in he already scheduled something for Christmas.